# Show that any solution of $x' = X(x)$ it is defined for all $t > 0$.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If $X=(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ is a vector field of class $C^1$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $V$ it is a differentiable function in $\mathbb{R^n}$ such that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_i}(x)X_i(x) \leq 0 $$ and $V(x)\geq |x|^2$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that any solution of $x' = X(x)$ it  is defined for all $t>0$.

Comment: You mean $V(x) \ge \vert x \vert^2 \forall x \in \Bbb R^n$, right?

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing exactly what the question is, what you want to show.  The phrase "it is set" is difficult for me.  Could you clarify?  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis yes, it's correct

Comment: @RobertLewis I want to prove that the solution is defined for all $t>0$

Comment: Very good!  Thanks for clarifying so swiftly.  Thinking, please wait . . . ;-)!!!

Comment: Also, I edited your question in accord with these comments.  Hope it's OK!  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis , spirit of Lyapunov and trajectory that doesn't leave some closed domain awaits ;)

Comment: @Evgeny:  Indeed, like Marley's ghost it knocks at our front door!  Merry Christmas, both early and late!  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis thank you, i am brazilian :)

Comment: S'all good, glad to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Look at $y_t = V(x_t)$. Compute $\dot{y}_t$ and use the given to show that $\dot{y}_t \leq 0$.

Now, integrate from 0 to $t$, and notice that $|x_t|^2 \leq y_t$ by the given.

Comment: Sorry, I could not complete the exercise with your tip